# Show vcard data in a uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, vcf-vcard

Good evening.

I'm developing a QRcode reader and I have one question.

When I read a vcard, I want to show the contact data in a UItableview like the contact's default uitablview in iPhone.

I want to show the contact data as above:

[image: contact view]

And I want to add the option to save to.

I want to know how can I do it. I have to manually program the view or is there some easier way to do it?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

```
CFDataRef vCardData = (CFDataRef)[vCard dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        ABAddressBookRef addressBook = [AddressBook Instance].addressBook;
        ABRecordRef defaultSource = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(addressBook);
        NSArray *contacts = (NSArray *)ABPersonCreatePeopleInSourceWithVCardRepresentation(defaultSource,vCardData);
        CFRelease(defaultSource);

        if (contacts.count) {
            ABRecordRef person = [contacts objectAtIndex:0];
            ABUnknownPersonViewController *unknownPersonVC = [[ABUnknownPersonViewController alloc] init];
            unknownPersonVC.unknownPersonViewDelegate = self;
            unknownPersonVC.allowsAddingToAddressBook = YES;
            unknownPersonVC.displayedPerson = person;

            UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:unknownPersonVC];
            [unknownPersonVC release];

            [self.navigationController pushViewController:unknownPersonVC animated:YES];
            [navController release];
        }
```

instead of creating custome Contact person View using table View use above code to first get all contact person record Ref and then display them one by one using
ABUnknownPersonViewController  or ABPersonViewController..

may be help you..

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the UITableView and implement all of its dataSource and delegate methods to draw the sections and cells. There's no free way to do this automatically, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably check out a table view framework such as the free Sensible TableView. These frameworks automate a lot of these common tasks and will save you a lot of time.